# c preprocessor add a space when concatenate numbers with sign

Tags: concatenation, c-preprocessor

It seems that the preprocessor adds a space when concatenating tokens that are signed numbers.
I tried this:

```
#define DECL_FL(IE) 1e##IE##f

float val[] = 
{
    DECL_FL(12),
    DECL_FL(-12),
    DECL_FL(+12),
};
```

the I run the preprocessor:

```
$ gcc test.c -E
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"

float val[] =
{
 1e12f,
 1e- 12f,
 1e+ 12f,
};
```

The first element in the array is correct. for the other two elements, a space is added between the number and the sign.
Why the preprocessor add a space? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is that `+12` isn't a preprocessor token, and neither is `-12`; rather, each of these are two preprocessor tokens (namely, `+` and `-` are punctuators; `12` separately is a pp-number).

We're essentially dealing with a pp-number, so here's the grammar rules for pp-number's:

`pp-number:
       digit
       . digit
       pp-number digit
       pp-number identifier-nondigit
       pp-number e sign
       pp-number E sign
       pp-number p sign
       pp-number P sign
       pp-number .`

Note here that `1`, `1e+`, `1e+12`, and `1e+12f` are all pp-numbers, but `+12` and `-12` are not.  This is what's biting you.

Per the preprocessor rules, a parameter in the replacement list is replaced by the argument token sequence; then, each `##` is applied.  The application removes `##` and concatenates the preceding token to the following token.  If that combination is not a valid preprocessor-token, the result is undefined.  (For reference, a preprocessor-token can be a header name, identifier, pp-number, character-constant, string-literal, punctuator, or a non-whitespace character that's not one of those; that's it).

When applying 1e##IE##f with IE being +12, you're essentially doing <`1e`>##<`+`><`12`>##<`f`>, using angle braces to denote individual tokens.  Both pastes, regardless of order (which is good, because the ## order is unspecified), will produce valid pp-numbers <`1e+`> and <`12f`>.  But the result leaves you with <`1e+`><`12f`> rather than the desired <`1e+12f`>.

> How can I avoid it?

Unfortunately you have to give up on passing `+12` and `-12` token sequences as an argument.  You could accept `+, 12` as two arguments, but you need to be careful when combining these in steps, since the order of `##` operators is unspecified and `+12` is not a valid preprocessor token (otherwise it might work, but would be allowed not to... and *that* situation is a potentially nightmarish time bomb):

```
#define PASTE(A,B) A##B
#define DECL_FL(IE) 1e##IE##f
#define DECL_FL_SGN(S,IE) PASTE(1e##S,IE##f)
float val[] = 
{
    DECL_FL(12),
    DECL_FL_SGN(+,12),
    DECL_FL_SGN(-,12),
};
```

...or you could simply use a sign specific macro; and strictly since `1e12f` and `1e+12f` are the same value (and nobody's going to see it anyway unless they just run the preprocessor), you can get away with only two macros:

```
#define DECL_FL(IE) 1e##IE##f
#define DECL_FL_E_NEG(IE) 1e-##IE##f
float val[] = 
{
    DECL_FL(12),
    DECL_FL_E_NEG(12),
    DECL_FL(12),
};
```

Answer (score -1):

the `##` is token pasting operator, this will not work if valid token is not formed after using it, as per C  `1e+12f` is not valid preprocessor token so it is trying insert space or it could lead to unexpected behavior, you can find it in following documentation.

`http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html`

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, but this is still wrong.  `f` is a floating point suffix in `C`, and `1e+12f` is a valid float literal in `C`, but even that doesn't matter because we're dealing with *preprocessor-tokens* in the preprocessor, and 1e+12f is a valid pp-number because `1` is a digit (a pp-number), `1e+` is pp-number "e" sign (which is a pp-number), `1e+1` and `1e+12` in succession are pp-number digit's (making them pp-numbers), and `1e+12f` is a pp-number identifier-nondigit (making it a pp-number); see grammar in my response; ref 6.4.8 of the standard.

Comment: FYI, regarding C grammar per se (which is distinct from preprocessing, which uses preprocessing tokens), `1e+12f` is grammatically a floating-constant, comprised of a digit sequence `1`, an exponent-part `e+12`, and the optional floating-suffix `f`; collectively this comprises a decimal-floating-constant which is a floating-constant.  Ref 6.4.4.2 of the standard.

Comment: @HWalters  I humbly disagree with you, it could be pp number but it is not valid token pasting operation, then what is being documented is wrong ? then what is the meaning of sentence in the document "However, two tokens that don’t together form a valid token cannot be pasted together." , effective same thing is happening here

Comment: From 6.10.3.3p3 of the C standard, which is authoritative, on describing the result of the `##` operator (see the rest of the paragraph): "If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined."  Note the explicit reference to preprocessing tokens, which are also defined in the standard.  gcc doc isn't wrong, it's just neither precise nor authoritative.